# Apply Computer Name and local hostname with System Image Utility

Tags: macos, automator

I am going through trying to create a NetInstall image using System Image Utility and am curious about how the "Apply Computer Name and Local Hostname settings from a file" option works under the Apply System Configuration Settings task in the Automator Library.

Could anyone perhaps give some insight about how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Try this format:-the Order is MAC Address, hostname (fqdn or not), Computer name (optional), Bonjour name (optional)

00:2c:76:8d:28:3b -automatic- Computer 1 Computer 1
00:2c:76:8d:28:2b -automatic- Computer 2 Computer 2
00:2c:76:8d:28:1b -automatic- Computer 3 Computer 3